# Gson parse complex object gives null object

Tags: java, gson

I need to parse a custom object that contains another custom object. I have two custom objects: `Page` and `Widget`, the `Page` object has a `HashTable` of `Widget`. I want to parse JSON and create an array of `Page` with various `Widget`. My request class is:

```java
public class GsonRequest<T> extends Request<T> {
    private final Gson gson = new Gson();
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    private final Map<String, String> headers;
    private final Response.Listener<T> listener;
    private final Map<String, String> params;

    public GsonRequest(String url, Class<T> classType, HashMap<String, String> params, Response.Listener<T> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);

        headers = null;
        this.clazz = classType;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.params = params;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        return headers != null ? headers : super.getHeaders();
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        return params;
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String json = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(gson.fromJson(json, clazz), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));    
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }

    GsonRequest<Page[]> req = new GsonRequest<Page[]>(url, V10Page[].class, params, new Response.Listener<Page[]>() {    
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Page[] response) {   
            List<Page> lista = Arrays.asList(response);   
            //callback.onSuccess(response);    
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println("Error:" + error.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that all the obejcts are `null`, where is the mistake?